# How have common PRBS polynomials been chosen, and what are they?

Tags: lfsr

Why are most common or standard (is there actually a standard?) PRBS uneven in their number of state bits, e.g. PRBS7, PRBS15, PRBS23, if there are plenty of generator polynomials that have even, byte-multiple numbers of bits, like 8, 16 and 24?

More generally, how have the common sequences, denoted with the aforementioned names, actually been chosen? Do they have any favorable properties compared to other LFSR maximum length sequences, or was it arbitrary?

Finally, where can I actually find what common polynomials are used? There are [precomputed lists of maximum length sequences](https://users.ece.cmu.edu/~koopman/lfsr/index.html), but no mention of what the common/standard ones are. If I instead search for "PRBS63" in Google, I can find mentions of that sequence, but not the actually used generator polynomials.

Answer (score 3):

The number of maximal-length sequence generators increases rapidly with the degree and so tabulating *all* of them is impracticable for large degree. A standard table of all *irreducible* binary polynomials of degree 16 or less (and a *few* selected polynomials of degrees up to 34) takes up 17 pages in in an Appendix of Peterson and Weldon's *Error-Correcting Codes,* (2nd ed.), MIT Press 1972 and they are much more densely packed than the prolix notation used in the OP's reference.  As to which ones are in common use or which have desirable properties, it depends on what is meant by desirable; *mathematically*, they are all equivalent, practically, there might be good reason to choose one over the other. One preferable feature might be *small number of nonzero coefficients* (which reduces the number of XOR gates (or instructions in software implementations).  Another might be smaller *overall* complexity of implementation: the primitive polynomial of degree 8 used in the Reed-Solomon code implementation in the NASA system was carefully chosen to minimize the *overall* complexity of the decoder (and no, it is not the first one in the Peterson&Weldon table).

Comment: By "standard", I meant governed by standard. I am completely aware of the infeasibility to tabulate them all, but I was wondering how the apparently "named" ones got chosen. "Small number of nonzero coefficients" makes perfect sense, though. As for the NASA one, can you point me to further material? I'm curious on how the generator polynomial they have chosen would incur less overall complexity than the locally optimal polynomial with the smallest number of nonzero coefficients.

Comment: Finally, do you know why the commonly used sequences have an odd number of coefficients, often but not always n*8-1 or even 2^n-1 (note that I am not taking about the length of the sequences), e.g. PRBS7, PRBS15, PRBS23 instead of PRBS8, PRBS16, PRBS24?

Comment: _All_ PRBS polynomials have an odd number of coefficients because they are, by definition, _irreducible_ polynomials (of a special kind), that is, they have no factors other than themselves and $1$. _All_ polynomials $f(x)$ with an even number of coefificients have $x-1$ as a factor (because $f(1) = 0$) and so cannot be irreducible. Hence, PRBS polynomials must have an odd number of nonzero coefficients.

Comment: Okay, I asked the wrong question. Why is the order of the highest coefficient usually odd? To repeat: Why do we commonly use PRBS7, PRBS15 and PRBS23, but not PRBS8, PRBS16 and PRBS24? LFSRs with 8 state bits have maximum length sequences as well, do they lack some other desirable property?

Comment: The short answer is Yes they do have some properties that make them a tad less suitable. Some of the details can be inferred from the extensive discussion in the paper D.V.Sarwate and M.B.Pursley, "Crossscorrelation properties of pseudorandom and related sequences," _Proc. IEEE,_ May 1980.